# Transverse Relativistic Doppler effect

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

This question originates from my previous question here
[Results of two equivalent scenarios in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308548/results-of-two-equivalent-scenarios-in-sr)

There is no specific need to visit my previous question to understand this one. I have made efforts to make this question clear and independent of previous one.

So what I understand is this: there are two in-line observers (H and H') that are connected by a tube and a third observer (T) travelling at velocity $v$ w.r.t to both H and H'. The motion is normal to tube i.e. the line joining H and H'.

Now, If H want to send a laser pulse to H', he does so by making sure he emits his laser pulse parallel to tube. But if T want to make sure his laser pulse reaches H', T must emit the light pulse at an certain angle $\theta$ when his position coincides with H. This is called transverse Relativistic Doppler effect.

What confuses me is this: T emitted the laser at angle $\theta=arctan(y/x)$ in his own frame. This angle will be seen as $\theta=arctan(y.\gamma/x)$ in the frame of H and H'. That is, the light will be emitted at some angle w.r.t the tube enclosing H and H'. If it is at some angle w.r.t to the tube it means it is not parallel to tube and hence must not reach H' (because it will strike the wall of tube at some time).

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me schematize the system. I think it is always a good approach when having those kinds of doubt, especially in special and general relativity where things might become rather counterintuitive. I will set $c=1$.

In the frame $S$, where the body $H$ is fixed at the center, motion laws are
$$
X_H(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\0\\0\end{array}\right),\quad X_{H'}(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\L\\0\end{array}\right),\quad X_T(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\0\\vt\end{array}\right).
$$
Here, $L$ is the length of the tube joining $H$ and $H'$ at the time $t=0$. As you can see, if $H$ wants to send a photon to $H'$, all it has to do is to send a photon along the $\hat x$ direction, that will move with law $x_\gamma(t)=(t,t,0)$. If $T$ wants to send a photon at $t=0$, it will have to send the same photon as $H$, aligned to the $\hat x$ direction.

Obviously, you want to know is $T$ has to send the photon with some angle in its frame. Let us then define the frame $S'$ where $T$ is at the origin: the Lorentz boost matrix will be
\begin{align}
\Lambda=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\gamma&0&-v\gamma\\0&1&0\\-v\gamma&0&\gamma\end{array}\right),
\end{align}
where $\gamma=\gamma(v)$. You can easily calculate the laws of motion in $S'$, as you always have uniform motion: by multiplying the $X$'s with the $\Lambda$'s, you have

$$
X'_H(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}\gamma t\\0\\-v\gamma t\end{array}\right),\quad X'_{H'}(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}\gamma t\\L\\-v\gamma t\end{array}\right),\quad X'_T(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac t\gamma\\0\\0\end{array}\right).
$$
As it is evident, the photon that you have to emit at $t=0$ cannot be aligned to the $\hat x'$ axis. We choose to parametrize time in the same way that is parametrized for $X'_T$: the photon must have motion law
$$
X'_\gamma(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{t}{\gamma}\\\cos\theta\frac{t}\gamma\\-\sin\theta \frac t\gamma\end{array}\right).
$$
For $H'$ to receive $\gamma$, it is necessary that there exist two values of the time parameters such as $X'_{H'}(t_1)=X'_\gamma(t_2)$: this implies
$$
t_2=t_1\gamma^2,\quad t_2=\frac{\gamma L}{\cos\theta},\quad t_2=\frac{\gamma^2 v}{\sin\theta}t_1.
$$
You must select the angle $\theta$ in order for a solution to exist (that is nontrivial, as you have three equations of two unknowns): in this case, you must have $\sin\theta=v$. You can use the second equation to calculate $t_2$ and have the meeting point (space and time coordinates).

So you have a solution in this frame: you must emit with angle $\sin\theta=v$. Let us study this solution in the reference frame $S$: returning back through the matrix $\Lambda^{-1}$, you have
$$
X_\gamma(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}(1-v^2)t\\(1-v^2)t\\0\end{array}\right).
$$
This is the 4-position of a photon traveling in the $\hat x$ direction, as predicted before.

I don't know how your guess can be interpreted. I don't understand what you would use for $y$ but you can try rethinking about your guess and confronting it with the schematization. It could look a little bit strange, but I think it's the best way to approach those problems.

EDIT: Typo fixing.

Comment: I will use $c$ to make my point clear.

Comment: I will use $c$ to make my point clear. The angle with which light pulse is emitted in T is $\theta=asin(v/c)$. This angle in the frame of H or H' will be $\theta=asin(\gamma.v/c)$. Am I correct till here?

Comment: No: in the frame of $H$ or $H'$ the photon is emitted parallel to the $\hat x$ axis, if the photon is emitted when $T$ is at $H$. I think that your sine transformation law is being applied incorrectly in this case.

Comment: Yes. That is where I think I am wrong. I am using geometric figures to convert sine between the two frames since I do not know the correct transformation. I am simply multiplying $\gamma$ with the side parallel to motion keeping side normal to motion as it is and ending up with statement just written in my previous comment. Can you please show the correct transformation of sine between inertial frames?

Comment: Let me clarify: if you want to understand how the angle changes with respect to the velocity, suppose to transform the vector $(ct,ct\cos \theta,ct\sin\theta)$ with a Lorentz boost with velocity $v'$ along the $\hat y$ axis, non necessarily equal to $v$: you get the vector $(ct(\gamma'-\gamma'\sin\theta),ct\cos\theta,ct(-\gamma'v'+\gamma'\sin\theta)$. This means that, in the moving system, the sine of the angle is given by $\sin\theta'=\frac{\sin\theta-v'}{1-v'\sin\theta}$. Now, in our case we start with $\theta=0$, so we get the results of our problem immediately.

Comment: Note that I'm starting from $H$'s frame, where I know that the photon is emitted along the tube. In $T$'s frame, one could obtain the angle $\theta$, and then transform this angle in the starting frame: in this case you have that the starting ange is $\sin\theta=v$, and when you take $v'=v$ to get back to $H$'s frame you have $\sin\theta'=0$, so you emit horizontally.

Comment: Umm...if I start with $sin \theta=v$ in T frame and get back to H's frame I have $sin \theta'=0$, so I emit horizontally. I think I should emit vertically not horizontally.

Comment: Because I have mentioned earlier that tube is perpendicular to relative motion. If H emits light horizontally, he will be emitting parallel to motion and normal to tube. This way his light will never reach H'. It is clear that H emitted light perpendicular to motion and parallel to tube i.e. vertically.

Comment: With "horizontally" I mean "along the tube", sorry for not clarifying before. Remember that I put the tube along the $\hat x$ axis, that is what I'm refering as the horizontal direction. Also, $\theta$ and $\theta'$ are angles starting from the $\hat x$ axis, so they are $0$ when you emit along the tube.

Comment: Duly noted. I am trying to check my calculations again

Comment: It is checking out perfectly mathematically. Still I wonder: Suppose there are laser pointer placed at origin of T and H. Light will emit parallel to pointer' body, right? Now T will tilt his pointer at some angle. Suppose H and T are equipped with compasses. Since in motion, the pointer in T frame will appear to shorter and rotated to H when he measures it with his compass placed over the pointer in T's frame. No matter how fast T is going, the angle read by H will never be horizontal. Except for when $v=c$.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, I forgot about the question.

I used your description of the system to build the frame in which $H$ is static. In this frame, the pointer $\textit{has to be}$ parallel to the tube if you define it as a thing that fires photons parallel to it, else the photon would not reach $H'$. Once you have described a system in a reference frame, you can use Lorentz transformations to obtain the description in any frame.

Comment: Let us say that in T (system T is not static) the pointer is inclined at an angle $\theta=acos(v/c)$ where $v/c=\beta$. For the two pointers in the system H and T to overlap when T and H coincide, the angle at which pointer in H has to be inclined is given by $tan\theta=\gamma\times tan(\beta)$. As you can see, the angle of inclination in H is not parallel to tube, rather it is inclined at an acute angle larger in value than $\theta=acos(v/c)$ and hence light emitted from pointer in H will not reach H'. Yet, Relativistic Doppler effect tells us that the light emitted from T will reach H'.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't trust your angle transformation law. By taking $\theta$ as the angle between the tube and the photon's velocity, clockwise, I am saying that $\theta$ changes as in one of my previous comments, not by a simple multiplication by the $\gamma$. Could you please indicate me a reference on that formula? Maybe the hypotheses of the formula are not met here.

By the way, we should move to chat (and I am having problems in creating a room right now), and we are using two different definitions for $\theta$, as yours is the complementary of mine (angle with $\hat y$).

Comment: https://www.phas.ubc.ca/~mcmillan/rqpdfs/1_relativity.pdf.        The question is on page 4.

Comment: I must apologize, I've done an error. You are right, if you have an horizontal rod in one of the frames $T$ or $H$, it will be horizontal in the other.

The situation with a rod modeling a "photon cannon" is more complicated. You have to model the rod's interaction with photons. I'd model it as a cylinder of small radius and reflecting surfaces. In $H$'s system the photon should be fired horizontally: if the cylinder is short enough and $T$ is not too fast, the photon will not bounce. Else, you have to take those reflections into account and write a more complicated path for the photon.

Comment: But the doppler effect is valid for all velocities less than c. I can arbitrarily assign any value to velocity of T and still the light from moving frame T will appear to be parallel to tube connecting HH'. However, the pointer in H will have to be kept horizontal to make it parallel to HH'. Let us further say that tube is hypothetical or that its inner surface is made up of black body which will absorb the photon, if photon collided with the tube.

Comment: Yes, the doppler effect is always valid. Simply, the photon will run along the tube if fired correctly both in $T$ and in $H$ frames. My remark on the velocity of $T$ was simpler: fixing the length of the tube, the photon (starting from the beginning of the tube) must escape the whole tube before being hit by the tube itself, that is rushing towards the photon at a velocity $v$. This can be visualized even from a classical viewpoint. If the surfaces are a black body, then the photon can be emitted or not, depending on the ship's velocity.